# TestCafe: Unable to upload file using single step upload control

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are trying to upload file using TestCafe code, but its not uploading the file.
There's no IFrame.
The input control is inside simple div>label structure

Kindly suggest. Thanks

```
<div>
<label>
  <div>..svg stuff..</div>
  <input aria-label="Upload an image" tabindex="0" type="file" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" data-testid="imageInputTest" class="ImageInputstyles__Input-sc-7878w-7 aosVy">
</label>
</div>
```

Code snippet:

```
fixture `Example`
.page `https://ourURL.com/YOUR PATH/`;
```

test('Upload Files test', async t => {
await t
.setFilesToUpload('.dx-fileuploader-input',
'path/to/file_to_be_uploaded/on/your/machine'
]);
});

We also checked that- its not uploading to the server.
More ref: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/setfilestoupload.html

Answer (score 2):

try

```
await t
        .setFilesToUpload(Selector('input').withAttribute('type', 'file'), [
            path
        ]);
```

Comment: You can see a detailed [description](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/basics/test-file-upload.html) of how to test file upload in TestCafe and inspect a runnable example [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/upload-files).